# Cherrypy quickstart consuming high CPU usage while idle

Tags: python, cpu-usage, cherrypy

I have the following CherryPy quickstart example:

```
import cherrypy

class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Hello world!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

I've found that if I leave it running, it is consistently near the top of the `top` output. For example, I left it running over night (not 24 hours) and this is the line from top:

```
PID  USER      PR   NI VIRT    RES     SHR  S  %CPU  %MEM   TIME+      COMMAND 
8284 pi        20   0  126212  13868   5792 S  7.2   3.1    112:51.88  python
```

And the server is not being interacted with over REST during this time, only idling. Any reason for this high CPU usage, or a workaround to prevent it?

It may be unrelated, but the below python code also uses a lot of CPU:

```
while True:
    pass
```

It uses a lot *more* CPU (rightly so, maybe) but it makes me wonder if the CherryPy quickstart is doing something similar to wait behind the scenes.

Comment: What is the CPU's configuration ?

Comment: This is on a gen 1 raspberry pi, running raspbian: https://pastebin.com/fQh7KJ3z

Comment: That's normal then.

Comment: I've now left it running on a much stronger computer for ~24 hours. It's still towards the top of the top output:  ```6684 username     20   0 1188720  23036   7608 S   1.0  0.1  10:36.97 python```(CPU% is 1.0) Here is the cat /proc/cpuinfo: https://pastebin.com/Mh6JfprX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think you should worry about it. And also you don't have to use `quickstart()` on production. Follow [here](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/deploy.html#id16) for using Cherrypy with `uwsgi` module for production purposes. It is much faster and lighter.

Answer (score 2):

One thing CherryPy is doing in background is checking for changes in files and imported modules and then re-execute the process. Switching the autoreloader off with `cherrypy.config.update({'engine.autoreload.on' : False})` uses less CPU. CPU usage dropped from 1.5% to less than 0.3% for me.